# Temporary Devise session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I create a variable that is only valid while the user is logged in Devise? For example: I need to have variable named "current_location" that may not be valid next time the user logs in as the person may travel around a lot. I don't want to save it in the database, because other users may be logged with the same account.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could set a `user_session[:current_location] = "Berlin, Germany"`. It should be unique to the Machine on which your user is currently logged in.

Comment: That was it! Please write it as an answer so I can mark it as selected :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By request:

You could set a `user_session[:current_location] = "Berlin, Germany"`. It should be unique to the Machine on which your user is currently logged in.